# React / Django/Webpack Update Existing Form & URL slug by primary key

Tags: django, reactjs, forms, django-rest-framework, react-router

I've created a form to add new client details, and would like to allow users to edit click on a link to update existing forms (with the fields pre-populated with the existing data) but don't know how to route the url (with the client primary key as the slug) on both the React and Django (with Webpack).

Creating a new client form currently has the url localhost:8000/client

And would like the existing form, say client with primary key 1 to have the form url be:
localhost:8000/client/1

At the moment, I've created a link for each existing client to connect to the existing client form in the client summary component:

```js
<a href={"/client/" + p.id}>
            <img src={edit} alt="pencil" />
          </a>
```

How can I get this corresponding id slug i.e. client primary key to another component i.e. the form component and assign to its state?

really appreciate it if someone can give some pointers, thanks!

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Comment: thanks for responding, I've added more details to my issue. my first main issue how to pass the id slug value from one component to another (the form component)